# Javascript - Check if (URL)-file exists over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, html

I already tried getting the file with this Code, the problem is, the code works with http requests but not with https request (which is what i need)

```js
function isThere(url) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); // XMLHttpRequest object
  try {
    req.open("HEAD", url, false);
    req.send(null);
    return req.status == 200 ? true : false;
  } catch (er) {
    return false;
  }
}

function setUser() {

  var user = document.getElementById("userName").value;

  if (isThere("https://dev.sentinex.de/ulogv2/" + user) == true) {

    alert("File exists!");

  } else {

    alert("File doesn't exist!");

  }
}
```

Does anyone know how i can change the code to work with HTTPS Requests or how i could rewrite it so that i could get HTTPS Requests?

PS: I am just requesting from my own domain - so no other domains for requests are needed.

Comment: What does the error say precisely?

Comment: calling https from http is violation of same origin policy. So if you are on http making a call to https, it ain't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please  posts the domain of the resource that executes the code. 
If you are on Http. You must use a **bypassSecurityTrust**